# Struct's id of type UUID changes everytime i try to access it

Tags: swift, struct, uuid

I have a struct which is parsed from JSON, but contains another struct `Article` that must be identifiable. It looks like this:

```
import Foundation

struct TopHeadlines: Codable {
    var totalArticles: Int
    var articles: [Article]

    struct Article: Codable {
        var title: String
        var description: String
        var url: String
        var image: String
        var publishedAt: String
        var source: Source
    }
    
    struct Source: Codable {
        var name: String
        var url: String
    }
    
    var json: Data? {
        return try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

}

extension TopHeadlines.Article: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID { return UUID() }
}
```

I need UUID generated to access image from newImages dictionary:

```
List(viewModel.articles, id: \.id) { article in
                    HStack {
                        OptionalImage(uiImage: viewModel.newsImages[article.id])
                        Text(article.id.uuidString)
                        Text(article.id.uuidString)
                        Text(article.id.uuidString)

                    }
                }
```

but three text views print three different UUIDs:

```
CC83B8AE-61B1-4A7D-A8A4-1B1E98C27CE7
545C1D28-F098-48A3-8C3C-A98BB54F9751
39B8383C-A2D8-46B0-BA51-1B861AF09762
```

How should I create ID for `Article` struct so it wouldnt be re-generated everytime?

Comment: That `id` property is a computed property, so every time it is accessed, it returns a brand new UUID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared `id` as a computed property, so by definition a new `UUID` instance will be returned every time you access the property.

You need to make the property a stored immutable property to ensure that the `UUID` never changes.

You also need to manually declare a `CodingKey` conformant `enum` and omit the `id` key from its cases to tell the compiler that `id` should not be decoded from the JSON.

```
struct TopHeadlines: Codable {
    var totalArticles: Int
    var articles: [Article]

    struct Article: Codable, Identifiable {
        var title: String
        var description: String
        var url: String
        var image: String
        var publishedAt: String
        var source: Source

        let id = UUID()

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case title, description, url, image, publishedAt, source
        }
    }

    struct Source: Codable {
        var name: String
        var url: String
    }

    var json: Data? {
        return try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `id` property in your extension is a computed property, so a new UUID (`UUID()`) is generated on each call.

Since you can't have stored properties in an extension, try adding it directly to the `Article` struct, like this:

```swift
struct Article: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var url: String
    var image: String
    var publishedAt: String
    var source: Source
}
```

This only generates a UUID when the struct is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

extensions cannot store properties, that's why you've implemented `id` as computed property, and each new `UUID()` is unique

the most obvious solution is to move it to move it to your struct

```
struct Article: Codable {
    let uuid = UUID()
    // ...
}
```

Declared like this it won't require value both in time of decoding or creating new object.

---

But if you can't edit this struct(which is probably why you're using an extension), you can do the following: extend your struct with `Hashable`, then you can access object `hashValue` which is calculated based on all properties so this value will be the same only for two objects with same values in all properties, which is usually fits good for an unique identifier

```
extension Article: Hashable {
    
}
```

Usage

```
Text("\(article.hashValue)")
```